# How do I turn off the Last Interactive Logon message?

Tags: windows-7, login

After entering my password at the login screen, I am presented with the following message:

```
Gilad (Gilad-PC \ Gilad)
Successful Login:
The last time you interactively logged on to this account was in [Date]
Unsuccessful Login:
No unsuccessful login is recorded
```

Is there any way to stop this message from appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done it by changing the

> "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisplayLastLogonInfo"

registry key to 0 (zero).

Comment: … which will last only until the next Group Policy refresh that sets it back to the GPO-defined setting.

Comment: At what ratio does this refresh occurs?

Comment: You can set the "Set Value" permission on the key "System" which contains DisplayLastLogonInfo to deny for SYSTEM account. This will make sure that th domain policy cannot update the said setting.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have [**Last Interactive Logon**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd446680%28WS.10%29.aspx) enabled.

To disable it:

1. type **Gpedit.msc** in run prompt.
2. Browse to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Logon Options.
3. Open **Display information about previous logons during user logon** and set it to **Disabled**
4. Press **OK**.

Comment: The run prompt cannot find `Gpedit.msc`. Where is this file located?

Comment: I've read that win7 Home Premium does not have Gpedit.msc, what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

### Your domain administrator controls this.

This is the Last Interactive Logon feature in Windows NT 6.1 that has been available since Windows NT 6.0, where it was called Previous Logon Information.  It's controlled by a Group Policy Object.

- You must be a domain administrator to alter the GPO.  The whole point of Group Policy is to enforce an *administrative policy*.
- GPOs can be edited with the Group Policy Management Console, which supersedes the old Windows NT 5.x Group Policy Editor.  The GPMC comes with the server flavour of Windows NT 6.x.  For workstation flavours of Windows NT 6.x, it is available as an add-on so that servers can be remotely administered from such workstations.  (Older versions of server and workstation similarly have the GPE as standard and available as an add-on, but of course ignore the policy object.)

### Further reading

- Microsoft corporation (2009-09-05). [*Active Directory Domain Services: Last Interactive Logon*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd446680(WS.10).aspx). TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2008-02-27). [*Previous Logon Information*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749292(WS.10).aspx).  TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2003-04-07). [*Administering Group Policy with Group Policy Management Console*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc739083(WS.10).aspx). TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2009-06-04). [*Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449475(WS.10).aspx). TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2007-12-01). [*How To Use the Group Policy Editor to Manage Local Computer Policy in Windows XP*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882).  307882.  Microsoft KnowledgeBase.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not login to change this GPO setting, try disconnecting your server from the network and then logging in with a user that has recently successfully logged in (Windows caches recent logins).